# Opencart region / state dropdown missing

Tags: opencart

I know this issue has been raised before and the solution was provided by shadyyx, but for some reason the solution does not work for me.

I am using the latest version (1.5.5.1) of Opencart with a custom theme (oskar). When a customer tries to register an account or goes through the checkout process and decides to create an account there, the region / state dropdown is missing or rather has no values in it. The website is wafflepantry.com, you can check if you like.

The following is my template/account/register.tpl file code...

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
<div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
<div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
  <p><?php echo $text_account_already; ?></p>
  <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2><?php echo $text_your_details; ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_firstname; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_firstname) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_firstname; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_lastname; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_lastname) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_lastname; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_telephone) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_telephone; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_fax; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <h2><?php echo $text_your_address; ?> </h2>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_company; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_city; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_city) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_city; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_postcode; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_postcode) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_postcode; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
          <td><select name="country_id" onchange="$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=account/register/zone&country_id=' + this.value + '&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');">
              <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
              <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
              <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <?php if ($error_country) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
          <td><select name="zone_id">
            </select>
            <?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <h2><?php echo $text_your_password; ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_password; ?></td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_password) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_confirm; ?></td>
          <td><input type="password" name="confirm" value="<?php echo $confirm; ?>" />
            <?php if ($error_confirm) { ?>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $error_confirm; ?></span>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <h2><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_newsletter; ?></td>
          <td><?php if ($newsletter == 1) { ?>
            <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked" />
            <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
            <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" />
            <?php echo $text_no; ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" />
            <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
            <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" checked="checked" />
            <?php echo $text_no; ?>
            <?php } ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($text_agree) { ?>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="right"><?php echo $text_agree; ?>
        <?php if ($agree) { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
        <?php } else { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="right">
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </form>
  <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').load('index.php?route=account/register/zone&country_id=<?php echo $country_id; ?>&zone_id=<?php echo $zone_id; ?>');
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    width: 560,
    height: 560
});
//--></script> 
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Best
Sev

Answer (score 1):

I have gone ahead and replaced the theme specific register.tpl in the directory 'catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/account' with the original OpenCart register.tpl. I have also replaced the theme specific register.tpl in the directory 'catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout' with the original OpenCart register.tpl.

This has fixed the problem without affecting my theme. Hope this helps the rest of us.

Comment: Note that you could just delete those two files in your theme folder which will use the default theme file instead. This is useful for when you come to upgrading as you won't have to copy over those files again if they've been modified

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is the route at the bottom. It's `account/register/zone` where it should be `checkout/checkout/country`. You should get an updated version of this theme for your store as this one is out of date

Comment: Thanks Jay! I had the same thought and contacted the developer of the theme. Unfortunately, I did not get any response nor does it seem as if there will be an update coming. Any way I can fix this in the code myself? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I have gone ahead and replaced the theme specific register.tpl in the directory 'catalog/view/theme/oskar/template/account' with the original OpenCart register.tpl. This has fixed the issue when you try to register an account by clicking on My 'Account --> Continue' without it affecting the theme. However, the issue still exists when you try to register an account at checkout. Any idea which file to modify or replace?

Thanks again!

Comment: `catalog/view/theme/your-theme-folder/template/checkout/register.tpl`